# Pagination in template typo3

Tags: pagination, typo3, realurl, typo3-7.x

typo 3 v7.6.1 !

if enable realurl `<f:widget.paginate>` work not correct.

in action table he return in page 'list'. In page 'list' default action.

need :

```
objects\controller\table\page\2
```

There is now :

```
objects\page\2
```

Paginator when generating links, ignoring the current action.

When I disconnect in realurl replacement, it works, but gets not readable reference.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Do you have custom RealURL configuration for this?

Comment: `'postVarSets' => array( '_DEFAULT' => array( 'controller' => array( array( 'GETvar' => 'tx_plugin[action]', ), array( 'GETvar' => 'unid', ), ), 'page' => array( array( 'GETvar' => 'tx_plugin[@widget_0][currentPage]', ), ), ), ),`

Comment: From this I can see that paginate is working as it should. Part which is missing is "controller\table". I guess action is table, so you can add in TypoScript on that page:

config.defaultGetVars {
       tx_plugin {
                controller=Controller
                action=table
        }
}

And this will force that action. Pagination is present, so you should not have any problem with that.

Comment: You are missing get params for controller and action. If you do not have it, your plugin is not aware of action it should use. And you can tel that via TypoScript. So your plugin is expecting Controller name and action name which is not present in URL, but you can add it via TypoScript :) Other option is to debug RealURL configuration.

Comment: Sets `tableAction` as Default. And in page `objects\` is correct paginate. But now I can`t see the gallery in url `objects\`. `objects\page\2` and `objects\controller\table\page\2` have same pid.

Comment: So the problem is RealURl configuration. Forget TypoScript, try to use RealURL Post Vars like this:
'postVarSets' => array( 
 '_DEFAULT' => array( 
  'controller' => array( 
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_plugin[controller]',
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_plugin[action]',
            ),   
  ),
  'page' => array( 
   array( 'GETvar' => 'tx_plugin[@widget_0][currentPage]', ), 
  ), 
 ), 
),